# How to operate on variables in R functions

Tags: r, function

I am trying to do following variable operations on data frame variables:

```
ptinr <- read.csv('ptinr.CSV')
ptinr$project <- gsub("_19T228z1xx","", ptinr$project)
ptinr$Subject <- as.integer(gsub("CTMS-",'', ptinr$Subject))
ptinr$Subject <- sprintf("%03d", ptinr$Subject)
ptinr$Subject <- paste0(ptinr$project,'-',ptinr$Subject)
```

I want to convert this to a function and pass the file name. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this kind of function?

```
f <- function(fname) {
  ptinr <- read.csv(fname)
  ptinr$project <- gsub("_19T228z1xx", "", ptinr$project)
  ptinr$Subject <- as.integer(gsub("CTMS-", "", ptinr$Subject))
  ptinr$Subject <- sprintf("%03d", ptinr$Subject)
  ptinr$Subject <- paste0(ptinr$project, "-", ptinr$Subject)
  ptinr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(fname) {
       read_csv(fname) %>%
          mutate(project = str_remove(project, '_19T228z1xx'),
                 Subject = glue::glue('{project}_',
                           '{sprintf("%03d", parse_number(Subject))}'))
   }
```